# Swift NSDate showing UTC when printing in debugger. How do I know if it's local time or utc when comparing date/times?

Tags: ios, nsdate, xcode7.3, swift2

I'm trying to write some code for a scheduling app and these schedules need to be based on the user's current time. Example, something is available between 5pm and 9pm on the current day. When I get the current time by using NSDate(), printing it results in utc: 2016-12-15 13:12:05 +0000. I know that it's in utc because if I add my local time zone offset in my head, it works out to be the actual time on my phone. The problem I'm having is when trying to create these time windows, sometimes the end time goes into the next day because there's no minus offset. Example, the user's time zone offset -5 and and it's currently 9pm local time. This will show 2am the next day which won't work because I need it to be the same day. How do you go about managing this kind of thing? I'm not sure if the print() function is even printing the right date. Is it adjusting to my machine's time zone? I need to see actual dates because I have to deal with time zones all over the world. I tried changing to a +5 times zone and all my scheduling code breaks. How can I ensure that my scheduler will always work with the user's local time?

If someone has done this kind of thing, it would be helpful if you can show how to create a start date, end date, and then how to compare with current date to see if it does or does not fall within the window. This needs to work for all time zones.

Edit: Here's something I don't understand. How do I handle dates that are in the form of a string like this: "2016-12-15T22:16:11+05:00" where the date and time is in "local time"? I know that the date is in local time because that's what was displayed on my phone when I generated it (on Dec 15 10pm). Now that I have that date, I want to know if it falls between a window of 8pm and 11pm on the 15th of December. How do I do that? When I convert that string to an NSDate, it coverts it to UTC (that's what I see in the debugger) and now the date is +5 hours from the local time (which goes into the next day). The problem now is that I'm comparing a date the lands on the next day with the current date, for example, the current date/time is Dec 15 9pm. But I need to know that the date represents Dec 15 10pm.

Comment: Post your current code that isn't working

Comment: FYI - when you see `2016-12-15 13:12:05 +0000` you know it's UTC because that's what the `+0000` means. That's the timezone. UTC is the `+0000` timezone.

Answer (score 2):

The first, key thing to understand is that `NSDate` does not represent a "date" in any way that you're probably thinking about. It represents a singular instant in time (without consideration of relativistic effects or other whatnot; just what you'd intuitively think of as "an instant in time").

That means, for instance, that an `NSDate` has no time zone. It has no location. It does not, itself, know anything about "days" or "hours" or "months." It is just the number of seconds that have elapsed since a specific moment in time.

Why do I go on and on about this? Because `NSDate` is almost never what you want for a scheduling app. When you say "2:00p on March 15, 2017" you mean a *nominal* time based on some calendar. Because calendars may change over time (DST rules in fact *do* change over time in unpredictable ways), you cannot know precisely what instant any future nominal time represents. You can guess, but you can't know, because the rules that map names to instants may change before then. And of course, even knowing the rules, that nominal time will represent different instants depending on what time zone it must be applied to. It's even possible for a nominal time not to exist at all (since DST might skip over it), or for it to map to multiple instants (since DST might skip backwards).

If you're doing scheduling, you want to work with `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`. These tools let you encode nominal times, apply time zones, and otherwise deal with the messiness of calendar systems. You should only convert these to `NSDate` when necessary, realizing that if it's a future date, the conversion is uncertain.

`NSDateComponents` also allows you to keep track of what you actually know about the date and what you don't, since most of it is optional. For example, it is possible to create an `NSDateComponents` with a `nil` time zone and no time. That allows you to express things like "Halloween is all of Oct 31, no matter what time zone you're in." But also express "this meeting is at 2:00p EST, which is 1:00p CST." Converting these things to `NSDate` prematurely invariably leads to Halloween starting at 10p on Oct 30, and other such nonsense.

---

Regarding your edit, I think all of your confusion is over what "2016-12-15T22:16:11+05:00" means. This is an absolute point in time. It's not local time. It's not UTC. It's a specific point in time that everyone will agree what that time is. Anyone in the world will agree that this is 1481822171 seconds after the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). People on the moon or on Mars would agree, too. This is an absolute point in time. The reason that's true is the "+05:00". That offsets the nominal time ("Dec 15, 2016 at 10:16:11pm") into an absolute time (1481822171 seconds after the Epoch).

When you turn this into an NSDate, the only information stored is 1481822171. There's nothing else. It's not "in a time zone." It's not "local." It's 1481822171. When you print the date's description, which is just for convenience, it prints "Dec 15, 2016, 12:16 PM" for me. But this is printed in local time *just for convenience*. This doesn't mean the NSDate is "in local time." If you want to print this, you should *always* use an NSDateFormatter and apply the time zone you want to apply. Never rely on `description`.

I know I keep saying the same thing over and over, but it seems to be the most difficult for people to really "get." **Absolute times have no time zone.** Time zones exist *purely* for nominal times because it makes humans happy. Nominal times have to do with how humans think about calendars. They have only limited relationship to how *time* works (which doesn't care about where you are on the planet, or which political system you're in and what calendar they prefer).

If you want to know if this is between some nominal times, you need to find out when those times actually are. So you'd do something like this:

```
// 8pm and 11pm on the 15th of December (in the +05:00 timezone).
var startComp = DateComponents()
startComp.year = 2016
startComp.month = 12
startComp.day = 15
startComp.hour = 20
startComp.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 5*60*60)! // +05:00

var endComp = startComp
endComp.hour = 23

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let startDate = calendar.date(from: startComp)!
let endDate = calendar.date(from: endComp)!

let targetDate = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: "2016-12-15T22:16:11+05:00")!

startDate < targetDate && targetDate < endDate // true
```

Comment: So is there a preferred "right way" to construct date/times for comparison using calendar and components? For example, if I want to create the current date/time on the user's phone and/or if I want to create a date/time from a string in utc or a string in local time? I look on SO and everyone does it differently. This is for swift 2.3. I haven't been able to upgrade to swift 3 for this project.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here by a "right way." `NSDateComponents` has various properties that you can assign to construct a date/time. To convert "now" (which is best achieved with `NSDate()`) to components, you need a calendar: `calendar.components(in:from:)`. Converting to and from strings is handled by `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: What I mean by "right way" is that if I have a date string when some type of event occurred, and it was saved in UTC, how can I use the calendar/components to convert that string to be used in a compare function against the user's current local date/time? Example: a user did something that caused an event which has a date saved in UTC. They travel and change their time zone. When I read in that date to be used to compare to his current time, what do I need to do with components to ensure that I'm doing the right comparison?

Comment: Here's one of the situations I'm faced with. The app pulls down a date string from the server that's in utc (i.e. just some arbitrary date in the past with GMT=0). That date means something to the app, like the last time something occurred. I need to be able to do some date comparison using the user's current local time and this utc time. What do I need to do to ensure that the comparison makes sense? You said I shouldn't use NSDate, but to use calendar and components. So both dates need to be constructed in a certain way for it to make sense. What is that way?

Comment: I've tried many ways and so far, when I change time zones, the code breaks. So obviously I'm not understanding how date/times are managed on iOS (and I'm very new to iOS development).

Comment: Use NSDateFormatter to convert the string to an NSDate. If the string includes the time zone (such as `+0000`), then it'll handle that automatically. Otherwise, attach the time zone (UTC) to the formatter. Then you have a moment in time. Compare that to `NSDate()`, which is also "a moment in time" unrelated to time zone. You're not comparing "date in one time zone" to "date in another time zone." You're comparing two instants in time. When you care about "instants in time" then NSDate is the correct tool, but those are independent of time zones.

Comment: If you actually care about time zones, so you care about "the moment that will be or was called 2:00p in New York" (even if that actual instance in time changes because the rules about DST change, which they do), then you want NSDateComponents. This is what is most commonly desired for a "scheduling app" (but you may mean something different by this).

Answer (score 0):

NSDate (or Date, in Swift 3) objects save a double that records an instant in time anywhere on the planet, independent of time zone. Under the covers, that double is the number of seconds since midnight January 1, 2001 in Greenwich UK (the "epoch date") but that is an arbitrary "zero point" and does not tie the NSDate object to a particular time zone.

You need to use a date formatter in order to display a date in your local time zone.

You could use the code:

```
print(NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(date,
  dateStyle: .MediumStyle,
  timeStyle: .MediumStyle))
```

That will display the date `date` in the user's local time zone and using their locale settings.

As for doing math on dates there are a number of methods that let you add time units to dates. Take a look at the docs for the `NSCalendar` class. For example take a look at the method `nextDateAfterDate(_:matchingComponents:options:)`

That will let you create an NSDate for 5 PM today, for example.

Comment: The first paragraph is very misleading. NSDate objects don't know anything about UTC, and the number of seconds since the epoch is unrelated to time zone (it's not possible to store it "in UTC;" it's a scalar difference between two doubles).  The `description` property does convert to a nominal time in UTC; that's the only "UTC" thing in NSDate.

Comment: @RobNapier, I edited the first part of my answer to try and clear up the confusion. Is the edit any better?