# Can't find the right date formatter (DateFormatter) in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I am getting date string from server like that "2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00". Below is my code for date formatter.

```
 let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 let serverDateString = "2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00"
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ"
 dateFormatter.locale = Foundation.Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 let currentDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: serverDateString)!
```

But it returns 2017-08-04 22:30:00 +0000. Which is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: in which format do you want your dateformatter

Comment: I want it to retuen me lie this 2017-08-05 00:30:00 +0000. It does return me in this format but with incorrect date and time. Right now it is returning 2017-08-04 22:30:00 +0000. Instead it should return 2017-08-05 00:30:00 +0000.

Comment: use this http://nsdateformatter.com/ can help you i think

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169923/swift-nsdate-showing-utc-when-printing-in-debugger-how-do-i-know-if-its-local

Comment: `2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00` and `2017-08-04 22:30:00 +0000` are the same moment in time expressed in different time zones. Like 7AM in London (GMT+0) is 9AM in Athens (GMT+2). Why do you expect `2017-08-05 00:30:00 +0000`? You want to strip the timezone info from the server's response?

Comment: Yes, i want to strip the time zone information from server. I want to display it as it is coming from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Swift 3**
You can change your server time string to UTC time `Date` as:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
var serverDateString = "2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00"
let index = serverDateString.index(serverDateString.startIndex, offsetBy: 19)
serverDateString = serverDateString.substring(to: index)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC")
let currentDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: serverDateString)!
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Apparently i had to ignore the time stamp from server, which you did. I was pulling my hairs off all day long yesterday. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ
```

This is correct date formate for your input string. Here is [the Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter) for more description.

Here is my code:

```
var strInputDateString: String = "2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00"
var dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ"
    //Set new dateFormate
var date1: Date? = dateFormat.date(from: strInputDateString)
dateFormat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"
    // Your Desire
var strOutputDateString: String = dateFormat.string(from: date1!)
print("\(strInputDateString)")
print("\(strOutputDateString)")
```

**output:**

```
Main input String:2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00
Converted String:  05-08-2017 04:00:00
```

For now, I tried to convert your date format with my custom. It's give me the perfect output.

Comment: This is what I'm using but it returns wrong date and time. The date should be 2017-08-05 what it returns is 2017-08-04. That is one day back. That's the problem.

Comment: @uzairshahzad I posted my code which I used to demo project. Its working fine.

Comment: The date returned here is fine. But time is wrong. It should be 00:30:00 but it returning 02:30:00

Comment: Its becuase it will convert on mytime zone.

Comment: How do i prevent it from converting to time zone? I want to display as i get from server.

Comment: You need to check in which timezone your server is. And you need to convert according to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code for parsing date is correct: `2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00` and `2017-08-04 22:30:00 +0000` represent the same time, just in different time zones. Your only problem is that `Date` doesn't actually store the time zone

Comment: So how do i get the desired result?

Comment: You want to change server side and your app side eg. server should return `UTC` then you set time zone in your dateFormatter to `UTC`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let serverDateString = "2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
dateFormatter.locale = Foundation.Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let currentDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: serverDateString)!
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It does not works. DateFormatter rerurn nil in this case.

Comment: Still same. DateFormatter returns nil.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your code is good.
I copied your data and ran it in playground.
What kind of format you want it be?

[image]

Comment: Try to run it on device. On device this is the result i get 2017-08-04 22:30:00 +0000. Which is wrong. The date should be 2017-08-05 and time should be 12:30:00 +0000

Comment: I got the same problem as yours before, check this [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177435/why-create-date-from-string-only-failed-on-real-iphone)

Comment: I checked your answer but i'm already doing this,  dateFormatter.locale = Foundation.Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

Comment: Actually, `08-05 00:30:00 +02:00` is equal to `-08-04 22:30:00 +00:00`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Date APIs, but if you simply want to get the date, this could help `Date(timeInterval: -7200, since: currentDate)`.  The server returned a date in GMT +02:00, but you need a GMT +00:00 date, so I just advanced date by -7200 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

The step you are missing is to again use your DateFormatter to format the date into a string. When you use print on the date, it will always show GMT. For illustration purposes, I've set the TimeZone to Berlin to match the original offset of +2:00.

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let serverDateString = "2017-08-05T00:30:00.000+02:00"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ"

// Hard set to Berlin
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Berlin")
let currentDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: serverDateString)!

// Your missing step
dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
```

*Remember that DateFormatters are about:*

- **Parsing** from a String - `df.date(from: String)`
- **Formatting** from a Date - `df.string(from: Date)`

Comment: I don't want to convert it to any time zone. It must be used as it is received from the server.

Comment: But your answer is correct, your seed time is +02:00 and your output is +00:00